# How to mod export script for magento

Tags: product, export

I need to export the following from all my products.

Sku
Name
Description

I have tried to use the dataflow profiles, it just has not worked for me at all. We are running at 100k products and I think its too big for that option, I have found this script though which exports sku and category_id

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//optional for products only visible in catalog and search
$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku", "category_ids");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
foreach ($products as $product){
$sku = $product->getSku();
$categoryIds = implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
fputcsv($fp, array($sku, $categoryIds), ",");
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Something like this would be ideal, but I have no idea how to modify it to export different things...

Can someone talk me through it?

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('description');
```

and then you can get them with:

```
$name = $product->getName();
$description = $product->getDescription();
```